# Caching - Django rest framework

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework, redis

**Use Case**

For example, an applicaton is data intensive, it has to show lot of data on frontend like feed, trending things, profiles etc.

And all these data *depend upon location*

Suppose, I have **GetMyFeed API**, the way I am Doing caching is :-

1. I am caching the queryset
2. I am taking cache key as **API payload**, because depending on it queryset will be formed.
3. Cache key is **API payload**.
   Cache value is **queryset**

**ISSUE , I AM FACING IS:-**

Changes on Database will be in Large amount per second, so to invalidate the cache, I have to clear the whole cache. But I don't think it is the right way of doing cache invalidation.

How can I update a single instance in list of objects which is cache value? And the main problem is single instance can be present in multiple queryset. So How will I update each copy of instance, which is present in different queryset, **in cache**?

Comment: You can try it https://pypi.org/project/django-cacheops/0.9.3/

Comment: How will this solve the problem, I can't understand